# Keydown delayed

Tags: c#, onkeydown

I have this to avoid infinite keydown looping:

```
    protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (bKeyIsDown) bKeyIsDown = false;
        bKeyIsDown = true;
        base.OnKeyDown(e);
    }
    protected override void OnKeyUp(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnKeyUp(e);
        bKeyIsDown = false;
    }
```

The problem with this is if I press 2 keys at the same time it only will do the action of the first one pressed. Also if you are pressing a key and while it is pressed you press another one the action of that one will be delayed.

Is there a way to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: Playing a sound while the key is down and stop it when the key is released.

Answer (score 3):

You could keep track of the current key held down. Something like this

```
bool bKeyIsDown = false;
Keys currentKey = Keys.None;

public event EventHandler OnKeyPressedOnce;

protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (bKeyIsDown && currentKey == e.KeyCode)
        e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
    else
    {
        currentKey = e.KeyCode;       

        //have your class handle this event and play the sound when this fires    
        //Could also create custom EventArgs and pass the key pressed 
        if(OnKeyPressedOnce != null)
           OnKeyPressedOnce(null, EventArgs.Empty);

        bKeyIsDown = true;
    }

    base.OnKeyDown(e);
}


protected override void OnKeyUp(KeyEventArgs e)
{
    bKeyIsDown = false;
    base.OnKeyUp(e);
}
```

If you want to handle more than two keys at a time, you could store a list of keys being pressed instead of just the current one.

Update from comment. Here's the basic gist of it handling the event.

```
private void KeyPressedOnce_PlaySound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (currentKey == Keys.A)
    { 
        MediaPlayer p1 = new MediaPlayer();
        p1.Open(new System.Uri(wav1Path));
        p1.Play();
    }


    if (currentKey == Keys.S)
    {
        MediaPlayer p2 = new MediaPlayer();
        p2.Open(new System.Uri(wav2Path));
        p2.Play();
    }
}
```

Comment: Still get looped when the key is down.

Comment: You need to play your sound within the `else {}` block. You can do this on a normal textbox by handling its OnKeyDown/Up events or if you're using the textbox many times then you could fire a custom event in that block that your main program handles.

Comment: I've updated the code to show an example of the event handler

Comment: Um now the problem is if you press 2 keys at the same time they won't play complete and/or if you press 1 key and while its pressed you press another it will play a part of the sound and play it again complete.

Comment: That might be the way you're playing the sound. The fact that the event is fired once is the job of the TextBox. How you handle that with the sound classes is separate. Maybe you're reusing the same sound reference so the old one is getting throw out.

Comment: MediaPlayer player1 = new System.Windows.Media.MediaPlayer();
        MediaPlayer player2 = new System.Windows.Media.MediaPlayer();

and then use this:

                       player1.Open(new Uri(path1.Text));
                        player1.Play();

                       player2.Open(new Uri(path2.Text));
                        player2.Play();

Comment: I don't think you can play two sounds at once with `MediaPlayer`. Try playing both at the same time without any of the key pressing stuff above.

Comment: They can play up to 8 as far as I know so the problem is the keypressing.

Comment: I tried your code with two wav files and they both cut out once the second one starts. Are you using WinForms or WPF? Also, are you creating a new MediaPlayer each time a key is pressed because that could be overwriting the old one.

Comment: Winforms and they cut because of the looping.

Comment: Ah, I was trying it in WPF. I'll give it a try in WinForms in a few moments.

Comment: Just tried it in WinForms, with the keys, and it's working fine for me most of the time. I just created a quick piano program and it worked fine although it cut off once or twice (not sure why but it could be the garbage collector since you're creating a new WMP instance each time a key is pressed).

Comment: You can prove that `OnKeyPressedOnce` is only being fired once by putting a `Debug.WriteLine("Play Sound");` and seeing how many times it comes up (should only be once).